# Strongswan IKEv2 auth - pubkey and EAP

Tags: vpn, authentication, strongswan, ikev2, eap

I'am trying to setup strongswan with pubkey and EAP authentication. To login users need to have certificate and valid credentials.

My certificate is ok. I tested pubkey auth and it was ok, also EAP is working, but when i trying run this two auth methods at a same time i have auth error.

I tested this on win7 and on android (strongswan client).

How can i setup this ? Is it possible at all ?

```
#ipsec.conf

rightauth=pubkey
rightauth2=eap-mschapv2

#ipsec.secrets

username : EAP "password"
```

ver. strongSwan U5.3.5/K4.4.0-116-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two (or more) authentication methods in IKEv2 requires support for [RFC 4739](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4739).

Unfortunately, a lot of clients don't support this, for instance, the built-in IKEv2 clients in Windows and macOS/iOS.

But combining certificate and username/password-based client authentication should work with the strongSwan Android app, if the client profile is configured appropriately ("IKEv2 Certificate + EAP (Username/Password)" is the VPN type to select there).